# I can't set UINavigationBar's barTintColor to clearColor successfully

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

There's a strange iOS 7 thing about UINavigationBar. If you try to set it's `barTintColor` property to `[UIColor clearColor]` or any color with a alpha = 0, it totally ignores that value. So for instance, if you write:

```
[[navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

It doesn't respect the "clear" part at all. Same result with `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha`.

But the most interesting part is, if you set `translucent` property to `NO`, then it will take the color you specified BUT with alpha 1. So if I specify `colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0` it will be set to pure red with alpha as 1.

How can I achieve it? Is there any possible solution to make it a completely invisible `barTintColor`, although it requires hacky methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a clear navigation controller try setting the background image of the navigation controller to use a clear PNG file (1x1 transparent, no color).

Comment: Great! It works! One detail is that you don't even need to create an image like that. Instead, set the `backgroundImage` to `[UIImage new]` through the pertinent method and it'll work.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I managed to get it working but I had to set `translucent` to `YES`. Without this, the bar was black.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
navigationBar.translucent = true
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: Works! Swift 5 will looks like: navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)