# Alpha isn't changing UINavigationBar's barTintColor

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to set the color of UINavigationBar to black with alpha 0.6 to see my interface. But if i use this code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.6)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

It still looks like with alpha 1.0:

[image]

How can I have it transparent with black transparent color?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of set barTintColor, you have to set navgationBar's background image with the same color.See similar question here:

[I can't set UINavigationBar's barTintColor to clearColor successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19737446/4975761)

But you have to get an image of this sepcial color.You can drop this image into your project,and then use

```
        let image = UIImage(named: "yourimage'name")
```

to get the image.

Or you can  add an func to your view controller :

```
 func imageFromColor(color:UIColor,size:CGSize)->UIImage{
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image;
}
```

and call this func in viewdidload :

```
    let color=UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
    let image=imageFromColor(color, size: CGSizeMake(1, 1))

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent=true;
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

This will works.

Comment: Okay I added this:             self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default) and it is clear, but I want there black color with alpha 0.6

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

```
func imageFromColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context!.fill(rect)

    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    image?.draw(in: rect)
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image!
}
```

**And as a UIColor extension**

```
extension UIColor {
    func toImage(withSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setFillColor(self.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        image?.draw(in: rect)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### You would have to get the image from Color as there is some problem with lower iOS version.Use this method to convert your UIColor to a background Image.

### Xmarin.iOS

```
private static UIImage GetImageFromColor(UIColor color, CGSize size)
            {
                var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
                color.SetFill();
                UIGraphics.RectFill(rect);
                var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
                return image;
            }
```

## call this method

var bgImage = GetImageFromColor(UIColor.FromRGBA(r, g, b, alpha), new CGSize(viewWidth, viewHeight));

Comment: Question referred to native iOS development, not Xamarin.